# Python - finding value position in a list and outputting as a new list

Tags: python, list

Currently learning python in my course and I'm a little confused on this part, unfortunately my next prac isn't until next week so I thought I'd ask here.

We're supposed to write a function called find() that takes a list, searches for the value in the list and returns as a new list of the positions in the list the number was found. Eg:

```
list = 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 3, 5
number = 3
```

the output would be: `0, 4, 5`

The question requires us to use a loop but not to use built-in functions, slice expressions, list methods, or string methods unless specified, with the only ones specified for this part being: `.append()` and `range()`.

We're given a file we're not allowed to edit:

```
import test_lists

list_A = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y']

print(test_lists.find(list_A, 'r'))
print(test_lists.find(list_A, 'b'))
```

From what I've attempted in a file named test_lists, the output gives `<function find at 0x0000000003B89D90>`:

```
def find(list1, listValue):

    findList = 0

    for x in range(findList):

        findList.find(list1, value)

    return find
```

anyone able to please push me in the right direction and explain it to me? We were told we could use `.append()` but I don't seem to understand how that would fit into this situation as from what I am aware append only adds to to the string. I feel like I'm pretty far off track.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `1, 4, 5` ?

Comment: Hm, I assumed it would count up from 0 and not from 1. That was just an example anyway. Looking to find the position of r in that list in the part below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can't use `enumerate` ?

Then, you you have to do the same thing by yourself : iterate over the indexes of the list and for each index, see if the element is the expected element. If it is, you had the index into your result list :

```
expected_element = 3
my_list = [...]
result_list = []
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i] == expected_element:
        result_list.append(i)
```

It's not very pythonic but if you have so much contraint, i think it's good

And if you can't use `len(my_list)`, you can get the size by iterate over a first time :

```
def size(l):
    s = 0
    for _ in l:
        s += 1
    return s
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 3, 5
>>> number = 3
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == number]
[1, 4, 5]

>>> list_A = ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y']
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(list_A) if x == 'r']
[3]
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin type/function `list`.

**UPDATE**

without using `enumerate`:

```
>>> lst = 2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 3, 5
>>> number = 3
>>> [i for i in range(len(lst)) if lst[i] == number]
[1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply however as stated in my question we can't use built in functions which would include `enumerate()`. We can only use `range()` function and `.append()` method to get the output.

Comment: Well then the quick change is: `[i for i in range(len(lst)) if lst[i] == number]`

Answer (score 1):

Will this do ?

```
def find(list1, listValue):
    found = []
    for index in range(0,len(list1)):
        if list1[index]==listValue:
            found.append(index)
    return found
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension would be the most Pythonic way to do this. But writing it explicitly for instructional purposes, here is another way to do it.

```
def find(number, numList):
    indexMatches = []                    # initialize your index array
    for index in range(len(numList)):    # iterate over the list of values
        if number == numList[index]:     # compare the number against the current value
            indexMatches.append(index)   # if they match, add it to the index array
    return indexMatches                  # return the list of indexes where matches occured

find(3, [2,3,7,2,3,3,5])
```

Output

```
[1, 4, 5]
```